# Domain of $\lim_{n\to\infty}|(n+1)x| < 1$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

In the process of doing the ratio test (for testing convergence of a function), I have the following issue. I am trying to find the convergence domain of $x$ in the following function:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}|(n+1)x| < 1
\end{align}
$$

The answer should be $x=0$. However, I do not know why this is the answer. Below is my workout:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)|x| < 1
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ |x|<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\ |x| < 0
\end{align}

Therefore, I thought that $x$ has no domain, because no absolute value of $x$ is smaller than $0$. I do not understand what is wrong with my reasoning.

However, in the 'model' answer, $(n+1)\to\infty$ and $\infty$ multiplied by $0$ is $0$, which is less than $1$. Therefore, the model answer for the domain of $x$ is $0$.

Comment: When passing to limits, strong inequality becomes weak, so you actually have $$|x|\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}=0\implies |x|=0\iff x=0$$ The model answer is right: if $\;x\neq 0\;$ then $\;|x|>0\implies \lim(n+1)|x|=\infty\;$

Comment: Okay. I can have a reference for your rationale: "when passing to limits". That will be helpful for me to understand this issue more.

Comment: it follows from definition, but for example for all natural $\;n\,,\,\,\frac1n>0\;$ , yet $\;\lim\frac1n=0\;$

Comment: I see. I have not learnt this in my calculus class...

Comment: Let's avoid manipulation. If $x\ne 0$, then by taking $n$ big enough, we can make $|(n+1)x|$ as big as we want.

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake by saying
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |(n+1)x| = |x| \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (n+1).
$$
This is assured to work only when when the limit exists, whereas the RHS limit does not exist. Your next couple of lines are (in their own nature) illegal for the same reason.

We do define $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$ in certain contexts (positive measure), but this is not one of them. What your "model" said does not look like the right solution, although it provides the right answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'the RHS limit does not exist'.

Comment: The sequence $\{n+1\}$ does not converge to a real number. You can extend your definitions so this particular equation holds, but your next one would still fail.

Comment: But, you mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} |(n+1)x|$ converge to a number then? What number and why?

Comment: That is by assumption, you are assuming that it converges, and you want to find this $x$ when it does converge.

Comment: In other words, are you saying that I cannot bring the limit outside the absolute sign, if the content within the absolute sign actually does not converge? I can only bring out the limit outside the absolute sign only if the content within the absolute sign converges?

Comment: I suggest you find a textbook that proves the validity of operations (additions, multiplications, inverse, etc.) on limit with rigour. There you will see that all these operations have a common premise, which is that the limits actually exist.